# How to change position in the animation

Tags: animation

Can I somehow connect the elements so that they rotate together?

I know that I can use ctrl+j but then they will merge permanently (these elements were previously moved separately in the animation, so it doesn't work for me).

Here is a video https://streamable.com/qvi5fn

Comment: did you try to parent those smaller parts to big part that needs to rotate?

Comment: Once you've keyframed, when you play the animation, the objects will rotate around their own origin as pivot point, not around the pivot point that was set in the Transform Pivot Point of the 3D View. So as MikoCG suggests, you should parent your screws to the object for example